# Integration test that can be pointed both to WireMock and the real instance depending on where it runs

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I am participating in an integration project using "Spring Boot 2" and I would like to be able to run integration tests in the local and development environment against wiremock. But when the same tests are run in TEST environment I would like them to run against the real services and not the mocks.  The idea behind is that wiremock creates sometimes false sense of security this way executing them against the real thing we will now things actualy work.

My main problem is how to write the test in such way that it is as least as possible dependent on wiremock. The project is Spring Boot 2 project.

Example 1.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfiguration {

  public WireMockServie () {
      // initialize wiremock
  }

}

class MyIntegrationTest {

  @Autowire
  WiremockServer wiremock;

  @Test
  public void myTest() {
      //stubb something
      // test something
  }

}
```

Now this aproach is not very good. Because it exposes the stubbing process and wiremock to the test, therefore same test can not be executed against the real service.

Example 2.

```
class MyIntegrationTest {

      @Autowire
      private static WiremockServer wiremock;

      @BeforeAll
      public static setup() {
         if(springProfile.equals("local") {
             // initialize wiremock
             // do stubbing global at a single place global for all tests inside the test class
         }
      }

      public void teardown(){
         if(springProfile.equals("local") {
             // destroy wiremock
         }
      }

      @Test
      public void myTest() {
         // now the test is agnostic of wiremock
      }

    }
```

Example number 2 in contrast to Example number 1 is agnostic and can be run against the real instance. All wiremock initialization happens staticaly inside the setup method.

Although Example number 2 works I feel that there maybe a better way to achieve this behaviour.

My question is:

1. Most of the articles I have read online talk about direct manipulation of the WireMock instance and direct manipulation of the stubs. This makes the test non-agnotic and i dont see a good way to run them against the real thing. Is there a better way that **Example number 2** to write a test that can be run both against Mock and against the real service depending on the environment where the test executes.
2. I read a bit about spring-cloud-contract can this help me to achieve the desired behaviour.
3. Is my aproach totaly wrong ? The reason why I ask are all teh manuals where wiremock is manipulated directly but they never talk about actualy swapping wiremock with the real thing?